# Clearing multiselect list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently using multiselect.js from here:

http://loudev.com/

The problem is that I want to be able to re-render the multiselect box when I click a button, as that button will make the list be filled up with extra options.

There's an option to do `.multiSelect('addOption')` but there are no options to remove an option.

Is there a way I can do this?

I have tried to set the `ms-selector`'s `val` to `""` then refreshing `ms-selector` but all that does is clear out my table

Comment: Downloaded the code. There is no function that is created for that. But you can update the `addOption()` function and give those options `id`s. And when you want to remove it, just remove it by id.

Comment: How would I remove an option by id? That's what I wanted to find out to, but I wasn't successful